# I want a print out of App Registration with expiry days of secrets and certificates and the owners associated with App registrations

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I want an email print out of all the app registrations associated with my Azure Entra ID. In the list I want a remaining of days left until secrets or certificates have expired.
In addition I want in the html email the name of the "Owners" of the app registration.

I running this in an automation account, in a run book in Azure

I successfully get an email of all app registrations associated in my Azure Entra ID and the count down of how many days are remaining. What I am struggling with is not getting a list of the associated "Owners" . I would like this listed as Name and email of the owner.

This is my code below

```
$fromaddress = "AppRegExpiryReport@internaldomainname.com"
$recipients = "jc@internaldomainname.com"
$subject = "App Registration Expiry Report"

Clear-AzContext -Force

# Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

# Set and store context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext


$graphToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$aadToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.windows.net"
Connect-AzureAD -AccountId $AzureContext.account.id -TenantId $AzureContext.tenant.id -AadAccessToken $aadToken.token -MsAccessToken $graphToken.token

Write-Host 'Gathering necessary information...'

$applications = Get-AzureADApplication -All:$true
$now = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

$appregArray = @()
$appWithCredentials = @()
$appWithCredentials += $applications | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | ForEach-Object {
    $application = $_
    Write-Verbose ('Fetching information for application {0}' -f $application.DisplayName)
    $application | Get-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential | Select-Object -Property @{Name='DisplayName'; Expression={$application.DisplayName}}, @{Name='ObjectId'; Expression={$application.ObjectId}}, @{Name='KeyId'; Expression={$_.KeyId}}, @{Name='StartDate'; Expression={$_.StartDate -as [datetime]}},@{Name='EndDate'; Expression={$_.EndDate -as [datetime]}}
    $owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $application.ObjectId
  }

foreach ($appreg in $appWithCredentials)
{
    $owner = Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $appreg.ObjectId
    $timeUntilExpiry = new-timespan -start $now -end $appreg.EndDate
    $raw = new-timespan -start $now -end $appreg.EndDate
    Write-Verbose "Days to Expire $($timeUntilExpiry.TotalDays)"
    $timeUntilExpiry = [math]::Round($timeUntilExpiry.TotalDays,0)
    Write-Verbose "Days to Expire after Math operation $($timeUntilExpiry)"
    
    $timeuntilexpirycolour = "#009900" #Green
    if ($timeUntilExpiry -lt 60){$timeuntilexpirycolour = "#ff6600"} #Amber
    if ($timeUntilExpiry -lt 30){$timeuntilexpirycolour = "#ff0000"} #Red
    
    $customCert = '' | select DisplayName,EndDate,timeuntilexpiry,timeuntilexpirycolour,raw
    $customCert.DisplayName = $appreg.DisplayName
    $customCert.OwnerName = if ($owner -ne $null -and $owner.PSObject.Properties['DisplayName'] -ne $null) { $owner.DisplayName } else { "No owner information" }
    $customCert.EndDate = $appreg.EndDate
    $customCert.EndDate = $appreg.EndDate
    $customCert.timeUntilExpiry = "$($timeUntilExpiry) days"
    $customCert.raw = $timeUntilExpiry
    $customCert.timeUntilExpiryColour = $timeuntilexpirycolour
    $appregArray += $customCert
    $appregCount++
}
write-verbose "   $($appregCount) certificates found in this vault"



## Main script continues here

$expiredCerts = $appregArray | where-object {$_.EndDate -lt (get-date)} | select-object -excludeproperty "timeuntilexpirycolour" | sort-object -Property EndDate
Write-Verbose "Expired Certs $($expiredCerts)"
$notExpiredCerts = $appregArray | where-object {$_.EndDate -gt (get-date) -and $_.raw -lt 781} | select-object -excludeproperty "timeuntilexpirycolour" | sort-object -Property EndDate
Write-Verbose "Non Expired Certs $($notExpiredCerts)"

write-verbose "`nSummary:"
write-verbose "$($appregArray.count) certificates found"
write-verbose "$($notExpiredCerts.count) active"
write-verbose "$($expiredCerts.count) expired"

$html = '
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: 595959;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
        color:000000;
        font-size:13px;
        font-family:segoe ui;
    }
    </style>
<font face = "segoe ui">'
$html += "This is the weekly Azure AppReg expiry report."

$html += '<table>
<th>Name</th><th>Owner</th><th>Expiry Date</th><th>Days Left</th></tr>'
foreach ($appreg in $expiredCerts)
{
    $html += "<tr><td>$($appreg.DisplayName)</td><td>$($appreg.OwnerName)</td><td>$($appreg.EndDate.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'))</td><td><font color=$($appreg.timeuntilexpirycolour)><b>$($appreg.timeuntilexpiry)</b><font color=000000></td></tr>"
}
foreach ($appreg in $notExpiredCerts)
{
    $html += "<tr><td>$($appreg.DisplayName)</td><td>$($appreg.OwnerName)</td><td>$($appreg.EndDate.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'))</td><td><font color=$($appreg.timeuntilexpirycolour)><b>$($appreg.timeuntilexpiry)</b><font color=000000></td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"
write-verbose $html

.\sendEmail.ps1 -fromAddress $fromaddress -recipients $recipients -subject $subject -emailBody $html
```

I receive this error:

```
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandInfo(String commandName, CommandTypes commandTypes, SearchResolutionOptions searchResolutionOptions, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandProcessor(String commandName, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, Nullable`1 useLocalScope)
   at System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.CreateCommand(String command, Boolean dotSource)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.AddCommand(PipelineProcessor pipe, CommandParameterInternal[] commandElements, CommandBaseAst commandBaseAst, CommandRedirection[] redirections, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'if' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: looks like this line is the issue: `$customCert.OwnerName = if ($owner -ne $null -and $owner.PSObject.Properties['DisplayName'] -ne $null) { $owner.DisplayName } else { "No owner information" }`

Comment: cool - not sure how to fix it

Comment: you could use ternary operator `?` or just create a variable `$ownerName` and populate it  based ont he condition